# Awardspace Email Setting

Tags: phpmailer, email, php

I got a Award Space Mail Hosting account.I created that account only for the free email sending feature.
Tried

```
PHP mailer
swiftmailer ect..
```

But no use.Can anyone give me a full working code of php and mail form,so that i can just test it in my server .I cound send emails when using this file :

> http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-validation.html

But,i dont want that peace of code.I want a perfect code that can work on My server.

Sample code:(Has an html form submit form)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$myemail = “support@domain.dx.am”;
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = “From:Contact Form <$myemail>\r\n”;
$headers .= “Reply-To: $name <$email>\r\n”;

echo “Your message has been sent successfully!”;
mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

} else {

echo “An error occurred during the submission of your message”;

}
?>
```

**Or i tried doing the same with php mailer:**

```
<?php
require 'filefolder/mailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'localhost'; // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'support@whatever.dx.am'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypassword'; // SMTP password


$mail->From = 'support@whatever.dx.am';
$mail->FromName = 'Support';

$mail->AddAddress('anything@gmail.com'… // Name is optional


$mail->WordWrap = 50; // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';

?>
```

I am doing something wrong. But cant figure out what. Can anyone help me out .

Comment: Are you getting an error (is yes, what is it?) or are you getting a success but the emails are never sent ?

Comment: I am getting a blank screen. No errors.But the emails are never sent.

Comment: Where is your PHP code hosted ? Is it on awardspace ?

Comment: Yes. it is hosted as a free domain in awardspace.

Answer (score 0):

The 'from' header should be an existing email account inside your Email Manager of your Hosting Control Panel. 
as their FAQ says:

> Tip: Please note that the 'From' header should be an existing email account inside your Email Manager of your Hosting Control Panel.

[FAQ](http://www.awardspace.com/contacts/faq-help)